# Outlook integration with another server c#

Tags: c#, outlook

Hi so i'm having this problem where i have a meeting application that will create reservation on my outlook calendar but i create it without sending mai,i create it in outlook folder,so my problem is what if i login with another server let's call my server is server "A" and my company server is server"B" so i login on server B and i make a reservation but on server B there's no MS outlook so i'm wondering if it can create on outlook folder on server A.
Sorry if my english are bad hope you all understand my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder to open another Exchange user's Calendar folder. If you do not want to install Outlook, you are pretty much limited to [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx).